# Socket keeps timing out

Tags: node.js, http, sockets, server

I have set up a nodejs http server using the default http module.

I want to keep connections open but they keep getting closed after 5 seconds, no matter what timeout I set:

```
server.on("connection", function (socket) {
  socket.setTimeout(300000);
  socket.on("close", function (reason) {
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(), "SOCKET CLOSED", reason);
  });
  socket.on("timeout", function (reason) {
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(), "SOCKET TIMED OUT", reason);
  })

  console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(), "NEW CONNECTION");
})
```

```
23:42:54 NEW CONNECTION 
GET /test.js 200 
23:42:59 SOCKET TIMED OUT undefined  
23:42:59 SOCKET CLOSED false
```

If I'm getting a timeout event I'm thinking it's the server closing the socket but just in case, I have set a keep-alive header as well:

```
Connection
    keep-alive
Content-Type
    application/javascript
Date
    Fri, 02 Feb 2024 21:42:54 GMT
Keep-Alive
    timeout=300
Transfer-Encoding
    chunked
```

The [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback) says:

> If timeout is 0, then the existing idle timeout is disabled.

So I also tried setting it to `0` but the result was the same, socket timed out after 5 seconds.

I'm using node v16.13.1 if it makes any difference.

Why is the socket getting closed and how can I prevent it from happening?

#### EDIT:

I just found that if I set the timeout after waiting 1s, then it works

```
server.on("connection", function (socket) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    socket.setTimeout(300000);
  }, 1000);

  ...
})
```

```
19:00:46 NEW CONNECTION
GET /test.js 200
19:05:46 SOCKET CLOSED false
```

Interestingly enough, there is no time out event, perhaps it's the client closing the connection first since the timeouts are the same but I could not care less at this point, at least it's working.

I'm leaving the question open in case anyone is interested in providing more information on this *phenomenon*.

Comment: It's a bit unusual to do this. Why are you doing this? Might help if there's an XY problem here. Is it possible your client is deciding to disconnect?

Comment: @Evert indeed it is a tad unusual, but nevertheless should be possible. If I'm getting a timeout event then I think it's unlikely the client be the culprit. I figured I may use the new connection/socket close event to monitor device status (only embedded devices will connect to this server). The alternatives are to manage these timeouts myself or use web sockets but I see this as a very clean solution if I manage to get it to work, with the added benefit of skipping connection overhead since the devices will be constantly sending data - not that big of a deal but makes my OCD really happy.

Comment: If you're controlling the client and the server, and want a continious stream of data, a regular old TCP socket might also be preferable!

Comment: @Evert yes there are many solutions, but I already have this set up and all the tooling is so simple, I'm asking because this is the ideal case for me as of now and it *should* work but I can't notice where the problem is.

Comment: what are you doing on the client site? An (abused) off the shelf HTTP client or a custom one based on sockets?

Comment: @Evert As of now I am testing with a browser. If I switch to a console and use `curl` for example the socket gets immediately closed and there is no `SOCKET TIMED OUT` message in the console, so this should mean, as expected, that the browser is respecting the keep-alive headers and is not closing the connection. In conclusion, the problem is *very likely* on the server side.